# UT error with mockito in Springboot 2.3.2

Tags: spring-boot

Did somebody face the following error? How to fix it? Thanks!

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<init>()V from class com.foreach.common.test.MockedLoader$BeanFactoryDecorator
21:28:17    at com.foreach.common.test.MockedLoader$BeanFactoryDecorator.destroySingletons(MockedLoader.java:120)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1061)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultContextCache.remove(DefaultContextCache.java:207)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultContextCache.remove(DefaultContextCache.java:172)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultContextCache$LruCache.removeEldestEntry(DefaultContextCache.java:337)
21:28:17    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.afterNodeInsertion(LinkedHashMap.java:299)
21:28:17    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:663)
21:28:17    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
21:28:17    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Collections.java:2588)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultContextCache.put(DefaultContextCache.java:142)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:129)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
21:28:17    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
21:28:17    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
21:28:17    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
21:28:17    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
21:28:17    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
21:28:17    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
21:28:17    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
21:28:17    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: Dumping a stacktrace is hardly a proper way of asking a question.

Comment: It looks like `com.foreach.common.test.MockedLoader$BeanFactoryDecorator` is calling a method in Mockito that it does not have access to. For that to happen, it must have been compiled against a different version of Mockito to the one that is being used to run the tests. Unfortunately, it's impossible to tell why that's happening from a stacktrace alone.

Comment: Hello,
I got the following error in some UT cases randomly. But the UT is working in 2.3.1 and 2.3.0. Is there anybody who has the same issue?

Comment: Probably not related, but I too have issues with 2.3.2 and Mockito. A unit test which runs fine on 2.3.1 now fails because `Mockito.verify()` claims that a method on a MockBean hasn't been invoked at all (though it definitely has, as debugging shows).